# Coding Around The Clock

Tags: code-golf, number, source-layout

Write a single line program two or more characters long that contains no [line terminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) and takes no input. For example, your program might be:

```
MyProgram
```

When your program is arranged into the shapes a clock's hands make at 12, 3, 6, and 9 o'clock, it needs to output the corresponding hour number. No other times need be supported.

Specifically:

- When your program is arranged like clock hands at 12 o'clock ()

  ```
  m
  a
  r
  g
  o
  r
  P
  y
  M
  ```

  running it should output `12`.
- When your program is arranged like clock hands at 3 o'clock ()

  ```
  m
  a
  r
  g
  o
  r
  P
  y
  MyProgram
  ```

  running it should output `3`.
- When your program is arranged like clock hands at 6 o'clock ()

  ```
  m
  a
  r
  g
  o
  r
  P
  y
  M
  y
  P
  r
  o
  g
  r
  a
  m
  ```

  running it should output `6`.
- When your program is arranged like clock hands at 9 o'clock ()

  ```
  ........m
  ........a
  ........r
  ........g
  ........o
  ........r
  ........P
  ........y
  margorPyM
  ```

  running it should output `9`.

## Notes

- The first character in your program is always placed at the center of the clock. (Note how there is only one `M` in the 6 o'clock example.)
- Any one non-newline character may be used to indent the program for the 9 o'clock arrangement. In the examples `.` is used, but space or `/` or `#` would be just as valid.
- For the 3 o'clock arrangement, no characters should be in the empty upper right region. (i.e. keep it empty, don't fill it with spaces.)
- The initial program arrangement (`MyProgram` as is) does not need to do anything. Only the 12, 3, 6, and 9 o'clock arrangements need to have correct, well-defined output.
- Code that only works as a function or REPL command is not allowed. Each of the four arrangements should be ready to run as full programs as is.

**The shortest program in bytes wins.** e.g. `MyProgram` has a length of 9 bytes.

Comment: I have no idea how to even begin doing this

Comment: You can see what programs you need to account for using this: `function all(e,n){n=n||" ";var i=e.split("").reverse().join("\n"),l=i+e.slice(1),r=i+e.split("").join("\n").slice(1),s=i.replace(/^./gm,n.repeat(e.length-1)+"$&").replace(/\n.+$/,"\n"+e.split("").reverse().join(""));return[i,l,r,s].join("\n\n")}` (javascript); `e` is the program, and `n` is the filler character

Comment: So, in Python, for instance, no `lambda`, no functions, and no REPL commands? This is going to take some miracle to get done on my part...

Comment: Is it OK if a character is printed and then erased with backspace?

Comment: And here comes the magic, thanks to @feersum

Comment: @R.Kap Not exactly. What I mean is each arrangement should be a valid full program - if it also works as a function or REPL command (as it might indeed in Python) that's fine.

Comment: @feersum Yes, that sounds ok

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes it a bit easier.

Comment: Here's a CJam script to generate all four codes from a single line and a padding character: http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=bDpMVyVOKk1MVyVOKkwxPitNTFclTDE-K04qTUwxPlclOnNMLGxjOlg7ZntYZVt9TFclYStOKl1OKg&input=TXlQcm9ncmFtCi4 Feel free to include it in the post.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That's the definition of meta-metagolf right there. There should be a challenge just for that.

Comment: I was gonna attempt this in Brainfuck, but it turns out the challenge fucked my brain before BF could.

Comment: @cat I believe that's impossible because programs `3` and `6` would be indistinguishable to Brainfuck as they only differ in whitespace.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yeah, I think so too.

Comment: Also out of curiosity, does "any character" for indentation include backspaces or NULs? What about Unicode combining characters?

Comment: @immibis Yes. Any character means any character.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## GolfScript, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
21;;3#9];6
```

Uses `#` as padding character.

### 12 o'clock

```
6
;
]
9
#
3
;
;
1
2
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=Ngo7Cl0KOQojCjMKOwo7CjEKMg&input=)

#### How it works.

- `6` is pushed on the stack, `;` discards it.
- `]` wraps the stack in an array (does not affect output).
- `9` and `3` are pushed on the stack, `;` and `;` discard them.
- Finally, `1` and `2` are pushed on the stack, and implicitly printed without separation.

### 3 o'clock

```
6
;
]
9
#
3
;
;
1
21;;3#9];6
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=Ngo7Cl0KOQojCjMKOwo7CjEKMjE7OzMjOV07Ng&input=)

#### How it works

- `6` is pushed on the stack, `;` discards it.
- `]` wraps the stack in an array (does not affect output).
- `9` and `3` are pushed on the stack, `;` and `;` discard them.
- `1` and `21` are pushed on the stack, `;;` discards them.
- `3` is pushed on the stack.
- `#` begins a comment until the end of the line.

### 6 o'clock

```
6
;
]
9
#
3
;
;
1
2
1
;
;
3
#
9
]
;
6
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=Ngo7Cl0KOQojCjMKOwo7CjEKMgoxCjsKOwozCiMKOQpdCjsKNg&input=)

#### How it works

- `6` is pushed on the stack, `;` discards it.
- `]` wraps the stack in an array (does not affect output).
- `9` and `3` are pushed on the stack, `;` and `;` discard them.
- `1`, `2` and `1` are pushed on the stack.
- `;` and `;` discard the last `1` and `2`.
- `3` and `9` are pushed on the stack.
- `]` and `;` wrap the stack in an array and discard it, clearing the stack.
- `6` is pushed on the stack.

### 9 o'clock

```
#########6
#########;
#########]
#########9
##########
#########3
#########;
#########;
#########1
6;]9#3;;12
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IyMjIyMjIyMjNgojIyMjIyMjIyM7CiMjIyMjIyMjI10KIyMjIyMjIyMjOQojIyMjIyMjIyMjCiMjIyMjIyMjIzMKIyMjIyMjIyMjOwojIyMjIyMjIyM7CiMjIyMjIyMjIzEKNjtdOSMzOzsxMg&input=)

#### How it works

- All lines but the last are comments.
- `6` is pushed on the stack, `;` discards it.
- `]` wraps the stack in an array (does not affect output).
- `9` is pushed on the stack.
- `#` begins a comment until the end of the line.

Answer (score 25):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 20 bytes

```
X   n-+g+aa0g+9a2c!v
```

There's unprintables in there, namely:

- After the `X` is `\x06\t`
- After the `c` is `\x03`

The same part of source code is run each time, using `g` on two parts of the source code to determine what to subtract from 12.

```
v                         Make IP move downwards
 !\x03                    Jump over the \x03
      c                   Push 12
       2a9+g              Get the char at position (2, 19), i.e. the \t for
                          3 o'clock, the \x03 for 9 o'clock, 0 otherwise
            0aa+g         Get the char at position (0, 20), i.e. first char on
                          the line after the X, \x06 for 6 o'clock
                 +        Add
                  -       Subtract from the 12
                   n      Output as number
                    \t    Unrecognised instruction - errors out
```

[12 o'clock](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=dgohCgMKYwoyCmEKOQorCmcKMAphCmEKKwpnCisKLQpuCgkKBgpY&input=) | [3 o'clock](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=dgohCgMKYwoyCmEKOQorCmcKMAphCmEKKwpnCisKLQpuCgkKBgpYBgluLStnK2FhMGcrOWEyYwMhdg&input=) | [6 o'clock](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=dgohCgMKYwoyCmEKOQorCmcKMAphCmEKKwpnCisKLQpuCgkKBgpYCgYKCQpuCi0KKwpnCisKYQphCjAKZworCjkKYQoyCmMKAwohCnY&input=) |  [9 o'clock](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHYKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICEKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAMKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGMKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDIKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGEKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDkKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGcKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGEKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGEKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIGcKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIG4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAkKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAYKdiEDYzJhOStnMGFhK2crLW4JBlg&input=) (looks misaligned due to the tab)

Comment: "12 votes 0 answers? Wait until Sp proves it's trivial please." –Helka, [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29256957#29256957)

Answer (score 1):

### [ROOP](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ROOP), 54 bytes

```
OW    3#H V  1#1  H#6  WO#H V>V1#OW V>V9#OW   2#OW   1
```

Uses `<` as padding character.

[12 o'clock](https://tio.run/##K8rPL/j/35BLAQzDufy5lLmMUHiWXGFcdkAM4xvC@R5Anj9QFKTWDMj2ALMMwWpALJgaY6h5YBP@/wcA) | [3 o'clock](https://tio.run/##VYw9CsAwCIV3T/HAE5hAIUtmt2zJMVJ6f7DGNoUq8n748JrzNBNC7KBGTOmXCnWqfjvLl9VT83axh3sNJ8Est5n8/osPAz6ZFR0QFkD5AEZbTe3CDrgWDjA9ImY3) | [6 o'clock](https://tio.run/##K8rPL/j/35BLAQzDufy5lLmMUHiWXGFcdkAM4xvC@R5Anj9QFKTWDMj2ALMMwWpALJgaY6h5EBPC4TxjqJ4wNH0gPWZILoCoAdlpCLcRwrdEcoEC0N3IPMP//wE) |  [9 o'clock](https://tio.run/##7ZYxCsAgDEX3nuJDThAFQSjObm56DEvvD7a2W8cMKYpZPkgewv9GPWs9WtslxZsIwwhYkWFJhpEMMyuAfwPwMizLsKC628y58crtW1E1gKR6uHRvLqfqZBzBEh5hunUtmXm67cT/EvGzyABKIvOKzyF35a6RUgEcRYDp7usrFk9jaxc)

### 12 o'clock

The `1` and the `2` that are near the top fall for 3 cycles. When they reach the `W` operator, the operator places the number in `O`, which represents the output.

The `1` in this part

```
1


V

H
```

fell for 2 cycles, the `V` operator moves it below and at the next cycle activates the `H` operator that ends the program.

### 3 o'clock

`O` are also objects that move and fall. Since the code now has a line with more than one character, all other lines are filled with empty spaces. All `O` moves to the right and fall, causing the `W` operators to have no place to send the `1` and `2`.

The only `O` that does not move is the one that is trapped in the center. The `3` above falls for 4 cycles to the `W`.

Then the numbers that fall are filling the 4 spaces between the `W` and`3`. When it is filled, another number can pass over all of them and reach the `H` operator that ends the program.

### 6 o'clock

```
1


H
#
6


W
O
```

Very similar to the 12, the `6` falls to the `W` and the `1` to the `H`. This occurs in 2 cycles, ending the program before the 12 case occurs.

### 9 o'clock

```
<9
<V
<>
<V
< 
<W
<O
<#
<1
<V
<>
<V
< 
<H
```

(I show a single column of `<` because the others do nothing).

The `V` picks up the `9` and moves it to the pipe below, which deflects the object to the left. The pipe `<` moves the object down and the next one to the right. The `V` operator put the `9` in the space below and then it is sent to the output.

The `1` makes equal movements and reaches the `H`, which ends the program. As the pipes move objects in the same cycle, all this takes a single cycle.